# docker pull fails with 503

Tags: docker

docker pull alpine

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
c9b1b535fdd9: Downloading
received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable
```

This is on Windows. How can I find out what is wrong?

My docker version is:

```
docker version Client: Docker Engine - Community  Version:          
19.03.2  API version:       1.40  Go version:        go1.12.8  Git commit:        6a30dfc  Built:             Thu Aug 29 05:26:49 2019  OS/Arch:           windows/amd64  Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community  Engine:   Version:          19.03.2 API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)   Go version:       go1.12.8   Git commit:       6a30dfc   Built:            Thu Aug 29 05:32:21 2019   OS/Arch:          linux/amd64   Experimental:     false  containerd:   Version:          v1.2.6   GitCommit:        894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb  runc:   Version:         
1.0.0-rc8   GitCommit:        425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f  docker-init:   Version:          0.18.0   GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue on the server, that is why your getting a bad gateway error. Did you try pulling a different image to see if it is working?

Comment: are you behind any sort of firewall or proxy?